# If column a contains certain text, see value of corresponding row, if it has changed from previous, make calculation

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I'm not sure if this will take a formula or VBA coding but either will be helpful. It is very hard to explain but here is the most simple way i can put what i am looking for: If column "A" contains certain text (in this case "ZS"), see value of corresponding row in column 3, if that value has changed from the previous value that corresponds with the previous "ZS" row, make calculation of "=((C10*0.11)+(C11*0.22)-H9*0.1)" of course with different reference cells. I have been working on trying to figure this out for a while now, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

VBA would be the easiest, cleanest way to do this. Is this what you're looking for? I'm not sure what your "reference" cells are referencing, but I used your example values.

```
  Sub test1
  Dim ZS1 As Range, ZS2 As Range, val1 as range, val2 as range
  Dim ws as worksheet
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
  Set val1 = ws.Range("$C$10")
  Set val2 = ws.Range("$H$9")

  'Find first ZS
  For Each ZS1 in ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1))
     If ZS1 = "ZS" Then
        'Step back to find previous ZS value
        For i = ZS1.Row - 1 to 1 Step -1
           Set ZS2 = ws.Cells(i, 1)
           If ZS2.Value =  "ZS" Then
              'If column 3 value in first ZS row is not equal to column 3 value in previous row then
              If ZS1.Offset(0,2).Value <> ZS2.Offset(0,2).Value Then
                 MsgBox ((val1.Value * 0.11) + (val1.Offset(1,0).Value * 0.22)-val2.Value * 0.1)
                 Exit For
              Else
                 Exit For
              End If
           End If
        Next
     End If
  Next ZS1
  End Sub
```

Comment: It hasn't worked for my workbook but i am trying to figure out the break down, I am not very good with VBA yet so i am learning as I go through this Code. Thank You for the Help, I wish i could upload a screenshot to show you what the data looks like

Comment: It says the "Set ws as ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet" is an error and expects an =

Comment: My careless mistake, yes it should be =. I've also changed the ZS1 range in my post.

Comment: Can you clarify how the reference cells in your final calculation are determined? What is their relation to the "ZS" cells?